# Using back button Mobile Single Page application AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, single-page-application

I'm using AngularJS to create a Single Page App (SPA) and am wondering how best to manage using the back button on mobile devices.

I created my application without views. One js form, one html page and no partials. The info is displayed using ng-show and a controller that helps hide `<div>` tags according to tab numbers assigned to them.

What I need to happen is for the application to NOT CLOSE when the back button is pushed.  But since I am not passing any params to the URL (because the URL never changes) is there a really good way to give functionality to the back button on the mobile device?

Here's a code sample, but I also included a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WoGsJZrCWRUBVKHMhGf2?p=preview) to try and better help clarify my need.

```
<div>
<a href ng-click="toggle = !toggle">=</a>
<ul ng-show="toggle">
  <li><a id="Home" ng-click="navi.selectTab(1); toggle = false">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="About" ng-click="navi.selectTab(2); toggle = false">About</a></li>
  <li><a id="Contact" ng-click="navi.selectTab(3);  toggle = false">Contact</a></li>    
</ul>
```

```
<div ng-show="navi.isSelected(1)">
```

or 
`<div ng-show="navi.isSelected(2)">`
or

```
<div ng-show="navi.isSelected(3)">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking to prevent the back button from leaving the SPA right away, you could use window.onbeforeunload() to warn the user that the back button will exit the app.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   return "Are you sure you want to leave?"
}
```

Otherwise to get your app to be stateful and allow the user to use back/forward buttons, you will want to use ui-router or angular-routes.

Comment: Ok. I can use this as an option. I was trying to avoid using the ui-router.

Comment: I've messed around with this a bit and even expanded my reading on it to try and better understand it, but this function doesn't seem to be working for me. @pascal-winter